# Error regarding the scope of two classes

Tags: c++, class, object, scope

I have a class named Engine.
An object of class TextureManager is inside of class Engine as well as an object of class Window.

My problem is that the functions inside of TextureManager cannot access the public functions or variables inside of class Window.

Is this an intended feature of C++ or do you think I am incorrectly declaring/defining one or both of these objects.

As you can see, inside engine there is a TextureManager and a Window.

```
class Engine
{
  public:
        Engine();
        ~Engine();


        Window gameWindow;
        TextureManager textures;

        SDL_Event event;

        int test;
};
```

Here is the header for class Window

```
class Window
{
  public:
        //Constructors
        Window();
        ~Window();

        //Getter Functions
        SDL_Surface * get_screen();

        //Other Functions
        void toggle_fullscreen();
        void render();
        void initialize(int screenwidth, int screenheight);
        bool handle_events(SDL_Event event);
        bool check_error();

  private:
        bool windowed;
        bool windowFailure;

        int screenWidth;
        int screenHeight;

        SDL_Surface * screen;

};
```

Here is the header file for class TextureManager

```
class TextureManager
{
  public:
        TextureManager();
        ~TextureManager();

        int new_texture(std::string filename);
        int new_section(int indexOfTexture, int x, int y, int width, int height);

        void render_texture(int textureID, int x, int y);
        void render_section(int textureSectionID, int x, int y);
  private:
        std::vector< Texture > textureIDs;
        std::vector< TextureSection > textureSectionIDs;
};
```

And this is the function I'm having trouble with. I have the error when accessing gameWindow in the function call SDL_BlitSurface()

```
void TextureManager::render_texture(int textureID, int x, int y)
{
  SDL_Rect coordinates;
  coordinates.x = x;
  coordinates.y = y;
  SDL_BlitSurface(textureIDs[textureID].get_texture(), NULL, gameWindow.get_screen(), &coordinates);
}
```

Comment: You may need to post a **very** short bit of code.

Comment: Yes, I think you've made the mistake of assuming that describing your code is easier than just posting a simple example!

Comment: fair enough, ill post some source right now

Comment: I just posted the source code. Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: Where does `gameWindow` inside `render_texture` come from?

Comment: gameWindow is an object of class Window that is inside of class Engine along with an object of class TextureManager. I'm assuming that two objects within the same class can access each others public members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, TextureManager instance does not know about the gameWindow instance of class Window. You may consider the following approach to allow TextureManager to interact with gameWindow:

```
class TextureManager {
public:
    TextureManager(Window& w) : m_refWindow(w) { /*...*/ }
    /*...*/
protected:
    Window& m_refWindow;
    /*...*/
}

void TextureManager::SomeMethod()
{
    m_refWindow.DoSomething();
}

Engine::Engine() :
    gameWindow(),
    textures(gameWindow)
{
 /*...*/
}
```

This way the `textures` object will be bound to the `gameWindow` object and will be able to call its public functions.`

Comment: +1 This is exactly the solution I settled on when I happened to hit the same problem the questioner is having.

Answer (score 1):

`TextureManager` doesn't know it's being used as a member variable of `Engine`, so it has no idea what `gameWindow` is.

Consider the fact that you could instantiate a `TextureManager` anywhere, including contexts where there is no `gameWindow` at all.  A member function can only "see" local variables, global variables, or its own member variables.

Comment: Oh, that makes a ton of sense. So what do you think I should do about it?